# React Jest Purpose of Act wrapper inside fireEvents

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, act

Im working on, on some tests using Jest and fireEvents from react testing library and i came across with this in the docs [act wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api/#act).

I cant understand why events need to be in an act wrapper.

What is the purpose of an act inside there? Can someone provide a simple example?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/threepointone/react-act-examples/blob/master/sync.md?

Comment: @slideshowp2 Of course i did. I has also an example there with button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", { bubbles: true })); which it is not wrapped inside an act and works fine. This is what i dont get.